# React.js infinite re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i got a issue with my code. My function "getNames" rerender may times, but i want it to render once? have you got any clue ?

```js
import grounds  from './../../UballersGroundsData.json';

export default function Groundlist() {

    function getNames(jsonObj){
        for(let item in jsonObj){
            console.log("item = " + item);
            for(let property in jsonObj[item] ){
                console.log(jsonObj[item]);
                // if (property === "groundName"){
                //     console.log(jsonObj[item][property]);
                // }
                
            }
        }       
    }

return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello world!</h1> 
            <ul>
                {getNames(grounds)}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: `getNames` is not rendering (executing) any extra. Can you create a runnable example? You can check https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-https-fe270?file=/src/App.js , it shows `console logs` correctly.

Comment: Yes but let's admit we change this `const grounds = {
  a: { aa: 1 },
  b: { bb: 2 }
};
` into this `const grounds = {
  a: { aa: 1 },
  b: { aa: 2 }
};
` and we have plenty objects. How can i retrieve all the "aa" property from all the object without writing "getNames(grounds.object.aa)" times the number of i have.

Comment: In that case, you can use `useMemo` hook. So, `getNames` will be called only when it should (i.e. when `grounds` changes).

Answer (score 1):

You should put your function inside of a [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), then set it to a [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with useState. Then, map out the list items for your list (assuming you are returning an array from your function). If you want it to only run getNames on the first render, you would set it up the useEffect hook with an empty dependency array. Code should look something like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import grounds  from './../../UballersGroundsData.json';

export default function Groundlist() {
    const [names, setNames] = useState([]) // Initial state with empty array

    useEffect(() => {
        function getNames(jsonObj){
            // your function logic here...       
        }
        const result = getNames(grounds) // Call your function
        setNames(result) // set it to names state hook
    }, []) // Empty array here means it will only use the useEffect on the first render.

return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello world!</h1> 
            <ul>
                {Array.from(names).map(name =>  <li>{name}</li>)}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you unfortunately, it sends me an error "TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) react hook to **memoize** the returned value i.e. **skip** unnecessary / heavy calculations due to change in other state, props or context variables.

**Example:**

```
import { useMemo } from "react"

export default function Groundlist(props) {

  const grounds = props.data // if grounds is passed as props from Parent component

  const groundsMemo = useMemo(() => {
    // do all the heavy calculations here 
    // (e.g. do the work of getNames function)
    
    // and return some JSX or Array (data)

    // returned value will be memoized;
    // means it will be re-calculated only if "grounds" changes
    
    // Hence, no unnecessary calls to getNames (heavy calculations)

  }, [grounds])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Use this if groundsMemo is JSX */}
      <ul>{groundsMemo}</ul>

      {/* Use this if groundsMemo is an Array (data) */}
      <ul>{groundsMemo.map(item => <li key={some_key}>
        {item.property}
      </li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useMemo` and `useCallBack` you want to optimize your react app.
React Official docs clearly described how to use it: [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)
[useCallBack](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: Thanks verry much !!

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call a function inside return scope of render.
It's normal for a component to re-render without proper treatment.

Taking in mind the other 2 answers

You can use the full power of useEffect, useCallback and React.memo to prevent anything from re-render.

```
import React from 'react';
import grounds  from './../../UballersGroundsData.json';

function Groundlist() {
  // initiate state
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([]);

  // This will prevent the Function from recalculate - useCallback
  const getNames = React.useCallback(function (jsonObj) {
    for(let item in jsonObj){
      console.log("item = " + item);
      for(let property in jsonObj[item] ){
        console.log(jsonObj[item]);
        // if (property === "groundName"){
        //     console.log(jsonObj[item][property]);
        // }
      }
    }
  }, []);
  

  // Will make function run only once and nevermore - useEffect
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setNames(getNames());
  }, [])

  return(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <ul>
            {names.map(a => <li>{a}</li>)}
        </ul>

    </div>
  )
}

// Will prevent React from try to re-render without changing in props, so as your component has no props, will never re-render without yourself unmounting first
export default React.memo(Groundlist);
```

In another cases you can control exact when the component should recalculate your names using the last argument of functions

```
useCallback(() => {}, []) //<---
```

For example

```
useCallback(() => {}, [updateState]);
```

when updateState change the function will be recreated.